# Moving database data from DEV to PRODUCTION, best practice?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, deployment

I have a development Django project using MySQL, and it is deployed at PythonAnywhere. I am able to push my code updates via GIT, and the Django migrations take care of the database STRUCTURE but my question is about data.

During development I may add a new capability that relies on master data which I enter in the DEV database as I develop and test.  When deploying I'd like to copy over the master data to the new database rather than re-enter it all. 
Is exporting and importing files the best way or is there a more professional way?

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to do this is by using the [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model) management command.

The output for this command can be used in executing the [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) management command.

Comment: Thank you this works.  Nice tutorial on this at https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata